# returning nothing when creating dataframe in R studio using for loop

Tags: r

i am facing problem of cannot create data frame in R studio, i tried to use for loop to make things easier but it fails to create. is that we cannot use for loop in data frame or we should put for loop outside of the dataframe? the code is as below

```
set.seed(1)
ran <-sample(1:3, 9, replace=TRUE)
obs = c()
z1 <- data.frame(
  for(i in 1:3){
    obs = c(obs, ran[i])
    X= c(X, q3data$X[ran[i]]),
    Y= c(Y, q3data$Y[ran[i]])
  }
)
z1
```

and here is the result

```
> set.seed(1)
> ran <-sample(1:3, 9, replace=TRUE)
> obs = c()
> z1 <- data.frame(
+   for(i in 1:3){
+     obs = c(obs, ran[i])
+     X= c(X, q3data$X[ran[i]]),
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"    obs = c(obs, ran[i])
    X= c(X, q3data$X[ran[i]]),"
>     Y= c(Y, q3data$Y[ran[i]])
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
> z1
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Comment: You do not need a loop. Try `ran <- sample(1:3)` (note you draw 9 random values but you only use the first three of them). Then `z1 <- data.frame(obs=ran, X=q3data$X[ran], Y=q3data$Y[ran])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way, try:

```
for(i in 1:3){
    obs = c(obs, ran[i])
    X= c(X, q3data$X[ran[i]]),
    Y= c(Y, q3data$Y[ran[i]])
  }
z1 <- data.frame(X=X, Y=Y)
```